# Using maven-buildnumer-plugin to stop builds if changes are not committed

Tags: svn, maven

I am using `maven-buildnumer-plugin` to add my SVN revision numer and build date to my web pages footer in Spring MVC project. All good... I thought.

I have no errors, but:

- My plugin configuration seems to be wrong. It does not really retreive the absolutly latest revision number for my project. I verified with 2 different IDEs chacnging and checking in files
- I would liek to FAIL my tomcat deployment to PROD (controlled by profiles) if I have any local changes that are not committed to SVN and/or if there are changes in SVN which I did not first check-out and include. So to make sure, the PROD is always the absolutely latest version and the revision can be reproduced.

My config looks like

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-beta-4</version>
<executions>
 <execution>
  <phase>validate</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>create</goal>
  </goals>
 </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
 <!-- Username/password stored in personal settings.xml -->
 <username>${plott.scm.username}</username>
 <password>${plott.scm.password}</password>
 <revisionOnScmFailure>0</revisionOnScmFailure>
 <buildNumberPropertyName>buildRevision</buildNumberPropertyName>
 <timestampPropertyName>buildDateTime</timestampPropertyName>
 <timestampFormat>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}</timestampFormat>
 <doCheck>true</doCheck>
 <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
 <getRevisionOnlyOnce>false</getRevisionOnlyOnce>
 <useLastCommittedRevision>false</useLastCommittedRevision>
</configuration>
```

This generates console output like:

```
    macbookpro:com.platt.myproject john$ mvn clean tomcat:redeploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Mereko
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, tomcat:redeploy]    
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] Deleting directory /Users/john/Documents/Workspace/Eclipse/3.6_Helios/com.platt.myproject/target
[INFO] Preparing tomcat:redeploy
[INFO] [buildnumber:create {execution: default}]
[INFO] Verifying there are no local modifications ...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/john/Documents/Workspace/Eclipse/3.6_Helios/com.platt.myproject && svn --username doe.john --password '*****' --non-interactive status
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/john/Documents/Workspace/Eclipse/3.6_Helios/com.platt.myproject
[INFO] Updating project files from SCM: skipped.
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/john/Documents/Workspace/Eclipse/3.6_Helios/com.platt.myproject && svn --username doe.john --password '*****' --non-interactive info
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/john/Documents/Workspace/Eclipse/3.6_Helios/com.platt.myproject
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: 56 at timestamp: 2011-01-20 11:35:48
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/john/Documents/Workspace/Eclipse/3.6_Helios/com.platt.myproject && svn --username doe.john --password '*****' --non-interactive info
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/john/Documents/Workspace/Eclipse/3.6_Helios/com.platt.myproject
[INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: trunk
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources

(...Continueing and finishing build and deployment)
```

Any ideas on how I can

- Get the really latest revision number that is checked in in SVN
- Make sure local changes stop the `PROD` build

THANKS

Comment: Small update: seems like MODIFICATIONS of existing files, i.e. adding/chanign text does not make the plugin stop the build, but DELETING e.g. a file or folders does. Any idea how to change that?

Comment: Concerning the different treatment of modifications and deletions, I observed the same, see [Bug in Codehaus JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-1644).